# What is this EV3 controlling app

Tags: ev3

What is this EV3 controling app that is used here:

https://youtu.be/Sjix76QjtMU?t=1m43s

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link in the video is broken but I could find it on the Google Play store.

It looks like it is called [Mindstorms Custom Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stefan.mindstormscustomcontroller).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for help. What is your favorate EV3 controller app?

Comment: @AllanXu I don't really use a controller app, the only one I have used is the official EV3 app so it's hard to recommend any.